Update "tax amount" on item level in woocommerce cart and order
I'm working on dynamically adjusting the "heraf moms" (tax amount) displayed in the WooCommerce cart and checkout based on specific conditions and calculations. My goal is to set the tax amount programmatically based on custom logic related to product attributes and fees.
Context:
I have a custom calculation that determines a taxable amount for specific products based on attributes like pa_antal (quantity type) and whether a subsidy (pa_tilskud) applies. I can calculate the correct tax value using custom logic, and it logs correctly, but I'm having trouble making the adjusted tax display correctly in the cart and checkout. I have created a custom tax rate to check for, so it only hits specific products and variables.
What I’ve Tried:
I’ve used woocommerce_before_calculate_totals to modify $item['line_tax'] and $item['line_subtotal_tax'] for cart items, but the changes aren't reflected in the cart or the final order.
I also tried modifying the tax rates using woocommerce_cart_get_item_tax_rates but didn’t see any effect.
My Questions:
What is the recommended approach for dynamically setting or adjusting the "heraf moms" (tax amount) for items in the WooCommerce cart and ensuring it persists through checkout and order creation?
Are there specific hooks or methods that reliably allow for changing tax calculations without being overridden by WooCommerce’s internal calculations?
How can I ensure that my custom calculated tax values are displayed and saved correctly in the cart, checkout, and order?
Any insights, examples, or recommendations on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Note: I can't add the tax myself as a "Fee" in calculate_fees, since it is required to show the price including taxes, on product level.
I have my code here :
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adjust_cart_item_tax_only_for_dynamic_class', 10, 1);
function adjust_cart_item_tax_only_for_dynamic_class($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }
    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2) {
        return;
    }

    $set_fee = 15767.00; // Fixed non-taxable fee for sets
    $single_fee = 8867.50; // Fixed non-taxable fee for single units
    $vat_rate = 0.25; // 25% VAT rate
    $target_tax_class = 'dynamic-tax-class';
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $item) {
        $product = $item['data'];
        $quantity = $item['quantity'];

        error_log("\n entire item: " . print_r($item, true) . "\n\n");

        // Only apply logic if the product has the target tax class
        if ($product->get_tax_class() === $target_tax_class) {
            $total_deduction = 0.0;

            // Apply logic based on 'pa_antal' attribute
            if ($product->is_type('variation') && $product->get_attribute('pa_antal') === 'Som sæt') {
                $total_deduction += $set_fee * $quantity;
            } elseif ($product->is_type('variation') && ($product->get_attribute('pa_antal') === 'Højre' || $product->get_attribute('pa_antal') === 'Venstre')) {
                $total_deduction += $single_fee * $quantity;
            }
            error_log('Type = ' . $product->get_type());
            error_log('pa_antal = ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_antal'));
            error_log('Deduction = ' . $total_deduction);

            // Calculate the taxable amount
            $totalIncludingTax = $item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax'];
            error_log('Line total including tax = ' . $totalIncludingTax);
            $taxable_amount = max(0, $totalIncludingTax - $total_deduction); // Ensure it does not go below 0
            $calculated_tax = $taxable_amount * $vat_rate;
            error_log('Taxable amount = ' . $taxable_amount);
            error_log('Calculated tax = ' . $calculated_tax); //Seems to calculate correctly

            // Adjust tax values
            $item['line_tax'] = $calculated_tax;
            $item['line_subtotal_tax'] = $calculated_tax;

            // Update line_tax_data array
            $item['line_tax_data'] = [
                'total' => [1 => $calculated_tax],
                'subtotal' => [1 => $calculated_tax]
            ];
        }
    }
    error_log("\n entire item again : " . print_r($item, true) . "\n\n");
    //the item shows corrects values and totals.
    WC()->cart->set_session();
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals(); // Optionally recalculate totals
    //Values not displayed in cart or order. 
}

